# Dynamically change the image color layout in a row in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclick

How to change the color of the image (not the background!) When I select item in the layout of a GridView? I overloaded method onItemClick(), but does not quite know how to refer to the address concrete element (the one selected).

Your existing code, row.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</GridView>
```

ImageAdapter.class:

```
package com.example.exchangemanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowImage);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Item item = data.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
            // My previous attempts
        holder.imageView.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY);
        return row;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class, overloaded onItemClick() method:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
            }
        });
```

As you can see in the file ImageAdapter.class, I can do painting over the image on the color, but I can not change the color back, when selected.

Comment: i have edited my answer and i think that should be work. better you check it out.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm such a "malicious", but unfortunately it does not work. I mean it's exactly what, but when I rewrite your code, it works but it does not matter what row I click, and has always selects only the first row. I tried to retrieve the position of X and Y, and then convert them into position row, but the application is kicked with the exception of "java null pointer exception".

Comment: i have update my answer (again) bro.. this time, i think it should be work as expected. check it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE ANSWER (AGAIN):**

First, you need to create an interface: right click on your package project -> New -> Interface (for ex. name it as OnMyGridTouchListener)
Second, add a public method on our Interface:

```
public interface OnMyGridTouchListener {
    public void onMyGridTouch(ImageView imgView, int action);
}
```

Third, use the interface inside your adapter. It should like this:

```
private OnMyGridTouchListener myGridTouchListener;
...
public ImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Item> data) {
    ...
    myGridTouchListener = (OnMyGridTouchListener) context;
    ...
}

...
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());

    // here is our interface should be used
    final ImageView finalImageView = holder.imageView;
    row.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            myGridTouchListener.onMyGridTouch(finalImageView, event.getAction());
            return true;
        }

    }

    return row;
}
```

Next, go to your activity and implement to OnMyGridTouchListener, should like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnMyGridTouchListener {
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onMyGridTouch(ImageView imgView, int action){

        if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            imgView.setColorFilter(Color.WHAT_COLOR_YOU_WANT);
        }
        else if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            imgView.setColorFilter(Color.WHAT_COLOR_YOU_WANT);
        }

    }
```

Last, its DONE!

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you very much. I have one little question as to the release of the field, again, change the color to gray? Something along the lines of the method, onNothingSelected(), which unfortunately is not in setOnItemClickListener()

Comment: Nothing has changed, only added the code you gave me (onItemClick method is exactly the same). I have no idea how I can completely back, and release the button to change the color.