# pointToPosition in GridView does not work

Tags: android, gridview, position

I have this code:

```
long position = imageAdapter.getItemId (gridView.pointToPosition(
(int) event.getX() (int) event.getY()));
```

Theoretically, this code should work, but when I display information Log.d function, I always get a "0" position. What am I doing wrong?

PS. The code I have implemented the method `public void onMyGridTouch` from this topic -> [Dynamically change the image color layout in a row in a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860560/dynamically-change-the-image-color-layout-in-a-row-in-a-gridview)

Comment: you log itemId, not posution, right?

Comment: Yes. The variable is called a "position" is a remnant of the earlier code

Comment: long position =
imageAdapter.getItemId, so position is itemId?

Comment: Well, yes. Method getItemId() returns the result of a long, so I assigned it to a variable

Comment: again what do you log: result of getItenId or pointToPosirion?

Comment: and what adapter are you using that you always get 0 as an itemId?

Comment: Yes. My class ImageAdapter have presented here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860560/dynamically-change-the-image-color-layout-in-a-row-in-a-gridview